# jQuery slideToggle doesn't show animation on live site but on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css, hamburger-menu

This is difficult to show, in jsfiddle it works as intended (https://jsfiddle.net/q4mwboen/1/)
But on my test page (http://uf.framefaktur.de) it doesn't - there is no animation of sliding down, it just appears (and when clicking again, it takes a while to dissappear - without animation again).
It's exactly the same code (less content)

So, I want to show a menu with jquery animation (slideToggle). What am I missing on the "live" site?

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="burger">
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            <span class="menu-icon">
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="head" style="display: none;">

    <div id="menu">

        Menu

    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  
  $(".menu-link").click(function() {

        $("#burger").toggleClass("open");
        $("#head").slideToggle("slow");
  
  });
    
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a new test page (on http://uf.framefaktur.de/), with the bare minimum code to re-create the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `event.preventDefault()` as the first line of code inside `$(".menu-link").click(..)`. This code prevents the url being called. In this instance, the code will add **#** to the URL. This will make the webpage go to the top.

In main.js, currently `$(".menu-link").click()` has a call to `$("#head").toggleClass("clicked");` but it *probably* should be `$("#head").slideToggle("slow");`

Also to ensure the web browser is not retrieving a cached version of main.js, you should consider appending a querystring e.g: `<script src="assets/js/main.js?v=1"></script>`

In main.js:

```
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
console.log('start loading main.js'); // TODO: remove console.log()

$(function () { // Make sure all JQuery code is loaded inside $(function ()
    $(".menu-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click > menu-link');

        $("#burger").toggleClass("open");
        $("#head").slideToggle("slow"); // TODO: Currently code has $("#head").toggleClass("clicked");
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log('scroll > window');

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150){
            $('#head, #header, #logo').addClass("sticky");
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('#head, #header, #logo').removeClass("sticky");
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollToTop').click(function () {
        console.log('click > scrollToTop')
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

    console.log('finished loading main.js');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I already had "sldieToggle", and now tried with toggleClass (and animate in css), neither work(ed). I always refresh with shift+F5 so I should get latest version.

It works - just not with the animation. But maybe this is a Chrome issue?

Comment: If the code works in js fiddler, then it's unlikely a Chrome issue. I think the next step is to create a test.html. Try and re-create the issue and then just play around with it. If you remove enough things, it will look like the JS Fiddler version.